# Flexbox Item: Border around image has lots of empty space, not exactly around image

Tags: css, flexbox

EDIT: uploaded to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evanF/bdon7ytg/6/

Inside of my flexbox container, I have some images. I want a border that goes exactly around the image, but instead, right now, there's empty space to the left and right of the image.

Not sure why?

Seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bowyj.jpg

Notice how the purple border has extra space inside to the left and right of the image.

*Note, the blue stuff is the background image in the

Not sure what to do here.

HTML

```
<div class="flex-container">

        <div id="myImages">

              <img id="one" src="images/img1.jpg">


            <img id="two" src="images/img2.jpg">


            <img id="three" src="images/img3.jpg">


        </div>

</div>
```

CSS code:

`````````````````````````````
body, html
{
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-image: url("img12.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;

    /*overflow: hidden;*/

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;



}


img {

    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

    max-height: 75%;
    max-width: 75%;

    object-fit: contain;
    flex: 1 1 0;
    min-width: 20%;
    min-height: 20%;

}

.flex-container {

    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 25vh;

}

#myImages {

    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    flex: 5;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

#one {
       border: 2px solid purple;

}

````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply,

```
img{
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

object-fit: cover; will cut off the sides of the image, preserving the aspect ratio, and also filling in the space

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer! Object-fit was causing the problems!

Answer (score 1):

You should either change `flex: 1 1 0;` to `flex: 0 auto;`
Or remove the `flex: 1 1 0;`

See codepen: https://codepen.io/Minegolfer/pen/xxxRNjo

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I tried it and it didn't work....either removing flex 110 or adding flex 0 auto.

Answer (score -1):

Give `width` and `height` in `px` to your `#myImages`.